# How to store base64 type string into Alfresco

Tags: php, alfresco, cmis

I want to store base64 string into alfresco. 
How is it possible in alfresco?

I used d:mltext datatype in my custom content

but it gives me below error

```
string limit exceed
```

Please help us.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not store it as `cm:content` ?